"No KVM!" error in GNOME Boxes after modifying an .xml file for a deleted virtual system
I was trying to set up bridging on Ubuntu Server 24.04 running in GNOME Boxes VM, using instructions from the Internet and the help of Perplexity AI. At some point Perplexity recommended modifying the VM's .xml file ~/.config/libvirt/qemu/<vm_name>.xml, adding the following block of code in <devices> ... </devices>:
  <interface type='bridge'>
    <mac address='52:54:00:12:34:56'/>
    <source bridge='br0'/>
    <model type='virtio'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
  </interface>

When I did this, the VM ceased to launch. I deleted the VM, and tried to create a new one, but couldn't do it because of that "No KVM!" error. I reinstalled GNOME Boxes; it didn't help. I also double-checked that virtualization support is still on in my CPU using kvm-ok and checking the presence of svm flags with cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep svm (I have AMD Ryzen5 6600H). My host Ubuntu is Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.

sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils


Could you add some details and context here?
